# Firebase react project marked as "deceptive site ahead"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I deployed my page with firebase hosting.

For some reason, I get this safety error:
[image: For some reason, I get this safety error]

Users can write and read data from firebase (comments, replies), but can't of course read data for users collection. Did anyone have same problem? What can I do about it?

Here are links to:
**live web site** https://interactive-comment-sect-a2a31.web.app/
**github repo** https://github.com/tr43om/Texto

Comment: It takes some time for Firebase to provide a SSL certificate. It does seem to be working now.. try accessing the website from any other device.

Comment: if I reload page, the error comes back again

Comment: how do you find its solution?? recently i have this same issue on my website

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase API key is open to see anyone. It means your database can be hacked anytime. I think this can be an issue. Try to put your keys inside .env file. That will make your application more secure.

Comment: Firebase keys are public by design, you cannot change that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could result with any of the following reason:

- Your site has been infected with malware
- Your site contains phishing pages
- There's an issue with your SSL certificate
- Your plugins have security vulnerabilities
- Your website has questionable links
- You offer suspicious downloads

To detect issue, use google search console and fix the issue as per recommendation.

[source](https://kinsta.com/blog/deceptive-site-ahead/)